# Android fragment unexpectedly close

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I use a holder activity with FrameLayout.

There I put a fragment with a listview. It works fine.

```
ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.fragments, feedFragment);
ft.commit();
```

Then I add another fragment.

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment targetFragment = new MainPhotoFragment();
ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.fragments, targetFragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Here I use add() instead of replace() to return to previous position of the listview when hitting back key. It works fine.

But it is possible to navigate to the third fragment from the second fragment.

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment targetFragment = new FullPhotoFragment();
ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragments, targetFragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Here I use replace to force the 2nd fragment to reload when hitting back key.

Sometimes back key from the third fragment works fine, it displays the second fragment that is reloading on appearing.

But sometimes (as I can see it happens first time when I try this steps) hitting back key from the third fragment leads me to the first fragment, closing the second fragment against my expectations. And the first fragment is reloading.

How to prevent this strange behavious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add() method will add Fragments to Container and any other fragments added to the Container will be queued back of the first fragment. They will be not visible until and unless first fragment made Invisible. I hope this is the problem you are facing. It would be good if you use replace() for the first-->second fragment navigation also.

Comment: In case of using replace() for the first-->second fragment navigation I then need to recover listview state when going back to first fragment. And I would not  like to download everithing again from the web and just going to saved position of the listview.

Comment: Then you have to download the data from web in the onAttach() of your Fragment and set the data to listview. It looks like you are calling webservice in onCreateView() that is why called multiple times.

Comment: But how can I get the listView in onAttach method?

Comment: why you required listview in onAttach method, you just write asynctask and execute that task in onAttach method. in the onpostexecute, notifydatasetchanged of listview adapter. Then automatically, it displays list items.